# Find repeated occurrences in String

Tags: c#, string

I'm currently trying to find all matches to a rule in a string and copy those to a vector. The purpose is to build an application which retrieves the top `N` .mp3 files (podcasts) from a community website.

My current tactic:

```
    public static string getBetween(string strSource, string strStart, string strEnd)
    {
        int Start, End;
        if (strSource.Contains(strStart) && strSource.Contains(strEnd))
        {
            Start = strSource.IndexOf(strStart, 0) + strStart.Length;
            End = strSource.IndexOf(strEnd, Start);
            string sFound = strSource.Substring(Start, End + 4 - Start);
            strSource = strSource.Remove(Start, End + 4 - Start);
            return sFound;
        }
        else
        {
            return"";
        }
    }
```

Called like this:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            Podcast.Add(getBetween(searchDoc(@TARGET_HTM), "Sound/", ".mp3"));
        }
```

Where `searchDoc` is:

```
    public static string searchDoc(string strFile)
    {
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(strFile);
        String line = sr.ReadToEnd();
        return line;
    }
```

Why am I posting such a big chunk of code?

This is my first application in C#. I assume my current tactic is flawed and I'd rather see a solution for the underlying problem than a cheap fix for lousy code. Feel free to do whatever you feel like though.

What it should do:

Find all occurrences of `"Sound/" + * + ".mp3"` (all MP3 files in the directory `Sound`, whatever their name, from the top of the target `.htm` file till `N` are found. Do so by returning the top occurrence and removing this from the `String`.

What it does:

It finds the first occurrence just fine. It also removes the occurrence just fine. However, it only does so from `strSource` which gets discarded at the end of the function.

Problem:

How do I return the modified string in a safe manner (no global variables or other improper tricks), so the found occurrence is properly removed and the next can be found?

Comment: Strings are immutable in C#, so if you're worried about any method having side effects, you don't need to.

Answer (score 2):

This is the wrong approach. You can use `Regex.Matches` to get all matches of the pattern that you want. The regex would be something like `"Sound/[^/\"]+\.mp3"`.

Once you have a list of matches you can apply `.Cast<Match>().Take(3).Select(m => m.Value)` to it to get the top 3 matches as strings.

It looks like you have a C++ background. This can lead to low-level designs out of habit. Try to avoid manual string parsing and loops.

Comment: Indeed, I have a C++ background. C# has some, uh, unnerving features which are new to me.

Answer (score 1):

Three flaws:

- First, these two things seem to belong together strongly, but you split them over two functions.
- Second, you forgot to use the startIndex parameter of Substring, requiring you to rebuild strings that are later discarded (this is a performance hit!)
- Third, you had a small error: you hardcoded the length of strEnd as 4.

I just made an extension method based on your code, which fixes these 3 flaws. Untested, since I have no VS on this computer.

```
public static List<string> Split(this string source, string start, string end) {
    List<string> result = new List<string>();
    int i=0;
    while(source.indexOf(start, i) != -1) {
        startIndex = source.IndexOf(start, i) + start.Length;
        endIndex = source.IndexOf(end, start);
        result.Add(source.Substring(startIndex, endIndex + end.Length - startIndex));
        i = endIndex;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't merging those violate the Single Responsibility Principle?